# How to flatten aggregations returned by elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, grafana

We're running reports over our application(s) log files, which are collected in an elastic search storage. Due to limitations in the stack, and the need to do some ETL-like transform (convert system terms to business terms at the very least), reports are being run by an external to elastic application, which first runs a query to elastic search rest API, and then uses the result to generate final report. Unfortunately, we can't use SQL-like interface at the moment.

For a report we run  aggregation query of the form

```
    "query" : {
            ### filtering criteria, not relevant to the question
        },
        "aggs":{
            "GroupBy": {
                "terms": {"field": "xxx"},
                "aggs": {
                    "CountDistinct": {
                        "cardinality": {"field": "yyy"}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Which returns something like

```
   "aggregations": {
        "GroupBy": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "GroupByValue0",
                    "doc_count": 30000,
                    "CountDistinct": {
                        "value": 800
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "GroupByValue1",
                    "doc_count": 20000,
                    "CountDistinct": {
                        "value": 200
                    }
                }

            ]
        }
   }
```

Current solution works fine for us, however if we can flatten it (actual query is a bit more complex with a bit more nesting) that would simplify other parts of the solution greatly. What we'd like to get as result is something as follows:

```
   "aggregations": {
        "GroupBy": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "GroupByValue0",
                    "doc_count": 30000,
                    "CountDistinct": 800
                },
                {
                    "key": "GroupByValue1",
                    "doc_count": 20000,
                    "CountDistinct": 200
                }

            ]
        }
   }
```

Is this possible to achieve with out of the box query and (or) aggregation capabilities?

Comment: Nope, you'll need to do this in your client code

Comment: Thank you @Val ! Given your elasticsearch and overall reputation, I'd trust you here, thank you for taking time to comment.